# App for changing between a work and private mode

Tags: applications, automation

I use my Mac for private and work. Between this two scopes I share a lot of configuration. Because of that I want to use only one account.

Here is my question:

Is a app existing with which I can change between a work and private mode? Here some things that the app should do:

- enable and disable my work email account
- mount and unmount a list of devices
- start a specific collection of software

Comment: Sidekick could be of help, [see this other answer here][1].     [1]: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/146453

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for [ControlPlane](http://www.controlplaneapp.com) which is location-aware or can change state depending on what devices are plugged in.

You will then need to configure it with a work location and a private or home location.

Things like launching multiple apps would be firstly set up in Automator and saved as a double-clickable script.

For example, I have one that launches Safari and opens a number of websites, then launches iTerm.

You would get ControlPlane to run this script when it detects the stage change.